# График в google charts с разными датами у показателей

Tags: javascript, массивы, график, google-chart

Построил график, используя Google Chart.
Данные:

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Дата', 'Проведенный платеж', 'Плановый платеж'],
      ['2013',  4000,      2400],
      ['2014',  10170,     8460],
      ['2015',  14660,     16120],
      ['2016',  11030,      8540]
    ]);
```

Конфигурация:

```
var options = {
    isStacked: 'false',
    height: 600,
    chartArea: {'width': '87%', 'height': '80%'},
    pointSize: 5,
    'legend':{
        position: 'bottom',
        alignment: 'start'
    },
    'is3D': false,
    hAxis: {
      format: 'y',
    },
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      'format':'###,### ₽',
    },
    series: {
      0: { color: '#166aac' },
      1: { color: '#eea809' }
    }
  };
```

Рендер:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('myPieChart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Точки данных расставлены в одну дату, например, для 2013 года на графике есть два платежа 4000 и 2400.

Но у меня данные представлены немного по-другому - есть проведенный платеж в 2013 и плановый платеж в 2014. Как можно разместить на данном графике эти данные?